# Fill arrays with data from block of string in java

Tags: java

I want to fill 4 arrays with specific data from block string

I got blocks like this

> 00:0035:0063:1705211023:00:
>   11::7027661000300976376:
>   99:59:07027661000300976376:::::
>   05:11:10000:::00 09:11:8510 07:::::1490:::
>   99:65:00:00:00:00:00:01000000000002140331410062269000000126300000000
>   99:64:00:00:00:00:00:00000355600200000000022700000000000000000001
>   99:01:227:1490:30:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:324
>   ****Segundo Ticket PANGUI**** 99:00:35:63:1705211023:0:1:19353:63895896:1490:0:::::
>   99:150:0|1|H014|35|63|210517102100|

and I want to check if  00:.. , 05:11:.. ,  99:65.. , 99:64... and 99:01...headers exists and stores data for specific field from each row, for example in line or row 99:65.. I will store the last field. If no exists one or more, I must be store zero, something like this

if exist 99:11 then Arr11 =specificfieldfrom9911, else arr11 = "0"

So that for each block have a structure or set of arrays that identifies the fields of each block
Arr00
Arr0511
Arr9965
Arr9964
Arr9901
how can I achieve this? any help would be great.

Comment: You should take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Find a logic with those header, learn how to read this data. Then you could easily dispatch the value to the correct array cell. But first, you need to find some pattern for each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you get the individual string you can use `startsWith("")` method on the strings. Eg. Assuming the string that came is on a variable called `inputString` you can use

```
if(inputString.startsWith("99:65")){
//do what you want to do
}
```

i hope this helps

Comment: Thanks djdere, it was very helpful!